# How I keep clicked button light up till I click another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm about to make row of buttons as menu bar and I'd like them to behave like I want. So lets say there is buttons `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. If I click for example button `B` I want it to light up and stay light up till I click another button (`A`, `C` or `D`). This kind of idea. I'm pretty sure it's not new one. And I believe there is more sophisticated way to do it than my version below.
I also want page to roll up on every button click.

```
$('#abutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#bbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#cbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#dbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Comment: can you provide the html

Comment: html is simple. Buttons are text which change color on click. With on and off css classes.

Comment: is it actually buttons or divs or spans or something else though?

Comment: something like this jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/ns7e5hyt/

Comment: Thanks man. This jsfiddle is just perfect. I made it too complicated.

Comment: you are welcome. anyway @depperm answer is perfect, so you can mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.button').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).addClass('on').removeClass('off');
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns7e5hyt/)

Comment: So easy as this. You just forgot to remove `off` from `$(this)`. Also you can type `$('.button').removeClass('on').addClass('off');` and solve it with just 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is that add some class to all button. For example `.btn`.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){ 
    $(".btn").removeClass("on").addClass("off");
    $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on"); 
});
```

If all buttons is in some parent, the code is simpler.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on").addClass("off");
});
```

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on").addClass("off"); 
});
```

```css
button.on { 
    background: yellow; 
    color: #000; 
}
button.off { 
    background: gray; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="abutton" class="btn">button a</button>
<button id="bbutton" class="btn">button b</button>
<button id="cbutton" class="btn">button c</button>
<button id="dbutton" class="btn">button d</button>
```